# Memory Leak in Java Servlet

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, servlets, out-of-memory

I'm attempting to use a Java Servlet, but I end up using all of the system memory and tomcat gets killed by the kernel with the following error:

```
2018-06-18T17:55:49.238505+00:00 myserver kernel: Out of
memory: Kill process 26117 (java) score 247 or sacrifice child

2018-06-18T17:55:49.238937+00:00 myserver kernel: Killed
process 26117 (java) total-vm:6298824kB, anon-rss:710520kB, file-rss:0kB,
shmem-rss:0kB

2018-06-18T17:55:49.241307+00:00 myserver systemd:
tomcat.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
```

Sometimes the files that I have to serve to end users are large (~200 MB). If I demand multiple of them, or sometimes only one I get the above crash.

```
case "xml":
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"igrfgridData.xml\"");
    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    String line = "";
    while ((line = cResponse.readLine()) != null) {
        if(!line.startsWith("comment") && !line.isEmpty())
             printWriter.print(line.toLowerCase() +"\n");
        }
    cResponse.close();
    break;
```

cResponse is a buffered reader from another server.  I'm not sure why this should use very much memory at all.  The lines are only ever 10's of characters long.

Wrinkle: free -m gives:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            925         416          73           3         435         323
Swap:          4095         174        3921
```

Tomcat is running with these memory parameters:
-Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -XX:PermSize=1024M

Am I running tomcat with too much memory allocated?

Comment: Does it still happen if you only read from the upstream server? Does it get better if you use chunked transfer mode? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: If the kernel runs out of memory, tell Java to use less, e.g. `-Xmx3g -Xms3g`. You could also try upgrading to Java 8 where PermGen has been removed, so you don't have to reserve 1 GB for it.

Comment: @EJP How do I use chunked transfer mode?  How can I get the stack trace?

Comment: 1. `HttpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0)`, however that only applies to the upstream request body: setting it for the response will be done automatically by Tomcat. 2. Oops, there is no stack trace, this is a kernel message, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I running tomcat with too much memory allocated?

**Yes**. Your `free` command says your system has in all 1G of memory, and you want to run Tomcat with 5G. 4G of swap doesn't help, you just need to increase RAM significantly. Once done, you could reduce both Xmx and MaxPermSize of 50% if you just need to send some files from one buffer to another.